# iOS 8 Today Extension- Load UIMapView

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6, ios8-today-widget

I try to add to my 'Today Extension' `UIMapView`, But after I add the `UIMapView` to the storyboard the widget view is stuck. If I delete the `UIMapView` everything works again...
Did anyone experience a similar problem? I also tried to write a new project and it reproduce :(

It seems to work better on the simulator, but it's still not running smoothly and stuck. 
When I run on debug mode from the Xcode on simulator or device it's runs good.

Thanks,
Guy

Comment: Did you link against MapKit? It also may be that MapKit is just too slow for today extensions - they tend to be killed by the system within a few seconds of running and MapKit takes a while to initialize.

Comment: Yes, I link against MapKit (and also import), and It's works on debug mode also on device so I think this is not the problem. You think that could be because it's too slow? The OS killed the widget? Intersting, Apple did not mention that you can't use with MapKit on the documentation, they mention other frameworks like Health Kit. Thanks.

Comment: I would try two things: 1. Implement widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler, save the callback block in a copy property, and don't call the block until your map delegate's mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap: method has been called by MapKit. Alternatively, install NSLogger from <https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger> and put log calls in viewDidLoad and dealloc to see if dealloc is indeed called too quickly. You can view the logs live on a Mac via WiFi.